# ModalDialog on Dialoge close run javascript

Tags: javascript, application-pages

Hello Iam coding a Sharepoint Solution with a Application page. In this Page i created a ModalDialog to open when a Button is clicked. The Problem is I want to run java script when the Dialog is closed. I think `dialogReturnValueCallBack` is the rigth way but it just doesnt work.
This is my Script:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     function showPopUp() {
         var options = {
             url: 'http://lbsps-2013/Anfragen/Lists/Klinik/NewForm.aspx',
             title: 'Neue Klink',
             allowMaximize: false,
             showClose: true,
             dialogReturnValueCallBack: callbacker
         }
         SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);

     }

     function callbacker(dialogResult, returnValue) {
        alert("HI");
     }

</script>
```

Comment: Is the page reloading without the alert?

Comment: No i dont see the alert and  i think the page is not reloading isnt this all client side?

Comment: try `dialogReturnValueCallback`, lower case `b` in `Callback`.

Comment: dialogReturnValueCallback with small b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameter names in JavaScript are [case-sensitive](http://jsonrpc.org/historical/json-rpc-1-1-alt.html#service-procedure-and-parameter-names).  According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff410058(v=office.14).aspx#sectionSection2), it's `dialogReturnValueCallback`.